# Odometer number format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement an odometer ( for prices) using this [odometer](http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/)

The problem is the number format. For example I have the price “150,75” that transform in “300,52”. The odometer put this “15,075” and “30,052” and that is incorrect. If I put “150,075 it works well but I can't change the prices format, I need to be “150,75” (two numbers after comma). How can I do it?

This is the code [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sandritascs/R44sd/)

```
var odometer = document.querySelector('.odometer');

window.odometerOptions = {
format: '(ddd),dd',
duration: 1000
};

var num="300,52";
setTimeout(function(){
odometer.innerHTML = num;
}, 1000);
```

Thanks

Comment: I think your trying to use this plugin for something it's not designed to do. You want it to format it like a price, but it's obviously designed to be used as an integer value. You'll need to either find a new plugin or write the code from scratch.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is trying to use a plugin in a way that the plugin does not support

Answer (score 0):

Apperently the odometer does not facilitate a change in decimal (radix) mark symbol. This is a dirty hack that overrides the symbol. Maybe you should get in touch with the author and ask if he can implement this properly. But, in the mean time, this works:

```
var odometer = document.querySelector('.odometer');
var num= 300.52;

od = new Odometer({
  el: odometer,
  value: 150.75,
});
od.update(num);
odometer.querySelector('.odometer-radix-mark').innerHTML = ",";
window.addEventListener('odometerdone', function(){  
    odometer.querySelector('.odometer-radix-mark').innerHTML = ",";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vg92t/

Comment: decimal numbers not needed

Comment: What do you mean, did he not say: "I need to be “150,75” (two numbers after comma)."?

Comment: he want it to display as 150,75 not 150.75

Comment: I need to be 150,75 not 150,075

Comment: With point (150.75) works not with comma (150,75) I will look if I could change.
Thanks for all